# VSCode snippets as extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I created a code snippet like this in the `snippets/snippet.json` file:

```json
{
  "Add subscription": {
    "scope": "typescript",
    "prefix": "!subscription",
    "body": "subscription: Subscription$0;",
    "description": "Add subscription property to a class"
  }
}
```

And I created a `package.json` file too:

```json
{
  // ...
  "contributes": {
    "languages": [
      {
        "id": "typescript",
        "aliases": ["typescript", "ts"],
        "extensions": [".ts"]
      }
    ],
    "snippets": [
      {
        "language": "typescript",
        "path": "./snippets/snippets.json"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If I put this snippet JSON into any project's `.vscode/mysnippets.code-snippet` file, then it's working fine. But if I publish as an extension and then install it, it's not working.

Any idea?

Comment: what if you remove the `scope` attribute and rename the file `typescript.json`

Comment: that's not helped

Comment: I tried to replicate this in a test extension but it always works when I launched/debugged the extension with `F5` and tested it in a debugged VSC

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong. In debug mode the VSC said `Congratulations, the extension is working!` but the snippets are not showed when I expect...
Could you check my extension please? Called `ddata-snippets` ... I'm fully clueless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that the extension is installed as a disabled extension.

Using debug mode a message tells the possible cause.

> you have a `"main"` property in `package.json` but not an `"activation"` property.

Because there is no `index.js` in this snippet extension, remove the line

```
"main": "index.js",
```

To get a cleaner package also define a file `.vscodeignore` file with content

```
.vscode/**
.gitignore
```

There is still a warning left

> [netdjw.ddata-snippets]: One or more snippets from the extension 'ddata-snippets' very likely confuse snippet-variables and snippet-placeholders (see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_snippet-syntax for more details)

You have to add them one at a time to see which snippet is causing this warning.